# Get actual value instead of ID in Address API for Country and State/Province

Tags: api, addresses

When am getting some entity using API, it's returning id reference only not the actual value.

**eg:**
$result = civicrm_api3('Address', 'get', array(
      'sequential' => 1,
      'conatct_id' => 10
    ));
Output:

```
enter preformatted text here
{
   "is_error":0,
   "version":3,
   "count":1,
   "id":6601,
   "values":[{
      "id":"6601",
      "contact_id":"1",
      "location_type_id":"1",
      "is_primary":"1",
      "is_billing":"0",
      "street_address":"#275, xyz",
      "city":"abcd",
      "state_province_id":"9300",
      "postal_code":"560082",
      "country_id":"1101",
      "geo_code_1":"12.7930129",
      "geo_code_2":"77.5051501",
      "manual_geo_code":"0"
   }]
}
```

In this example, state_province_id,country_id is returned. Is it possible to get state name and country name in the result?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This is possible in the "trunk" version of CiviCRM, and will be available in CiviCRM 4.7.15, releasing January 4, 2017.  Earlier versions of CiviCRM don't have a StateProvince API.

Using the "Join" feature of the API, you can pull in fields from related tables.  See my screenshot for how I would construct an address pulling in actual state/province names (and/or state abbreviations) as well as country:

```
    $result = civicrm_api3('Address', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => array("street_address", "supplemental_address_1", "supplemental_address_2", "city", "state_province_id.name", "state_province_id.abbreviation", "country_id.name"),
));
```

[image]

Before 4.7.0, API joins didn't exist - and before 4.7.15 there was no [StateProvince API](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19688).  So in the past, developers would either implement their own StateProvince API or use a hybrid of API and BAO calls.